# Search data in webpage search engine using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, firefox, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Automating the workflow open a web page url = https://www.infogreffe.com and enter the text in the search box and click the search icon

MY CODE:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.infogreffe.com")
alert = driver.find_element_by_id("dijit_form_Button_0_label")
alert.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("phrase")
search_field.clear()
search_field.send_keys("IMERYS")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('spinnerContainer').send_keys("IMERYS")
driver.find_element_by_class_name('button').click()
```

And webpage is loading for long time and then i got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ARC/PycharmProjects/SeleniumChallenge/info.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver.get("https://www.infogreffe.com")
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 268, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timeout loading page after 300000ms
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: When I load that url into my browser and view the HTML I can't find "dijit_form_Button_0". Is that element a button, or something else, and how is it labelled on the visible page?

Comment: its an alert message button and its id = "dijit_form_Button_0_label"